# Typescript generic with generic key with string value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following interface structure

```
interface Table<T> {
    data: T[];
    tableConfig: TableConfig<T>;
}

interface TableConfig<T> {
    fieldNames: Array<keyof T>;
    idName: keyof T;
}
```

I am guaranteed to know that by using **idName** value as a key for **data** I will always receive a string value. And I can’t figure out if I can somehow tell typescript about this without typecasting. Can someone help me with this?

UPDATE.
I will give more context. I have a common React component for working with tables. It may work with different data types. Inside table I have code like this

```
{data.map((row) => (
        <StyledRowItem>
          <td>
            <Controller
              name={row[tableConfig.idName] as string}
```

Сontroller only accepts strings, I can't modify it. But I know for sure that data sets for a certain key will have a string value.

Answer (score 0):

From the typescript [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#handbook-content):

> The keyof operator takes an object type and produces a string or
> numeric literal union of its keys

Which means if you have this obj:

```js
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

and do:

```js
type K = keyof typeof obj;
```

`K` will get a union of all the keys of the `obj`.
In this case: `"a" | "b" | "c"`.

Back in your example you have a `TableConfig<T>` and then you declare that the `idName` will be `keyof T`. But `keyof` of what? `T` could be anything.

Example:

```js
interface TableConfig<T> {
    idName: keyof T;
}

const ex1: TableConfig<string> = {
    idName: ... // `idName` type: "anchor" | "blink" | ... | "trim" | "valueOf"
}

const ex2: TableConfig<{path: string, enabled: boolean}> = {
    idName: ... // `idName` type: "enabled" | "path"
}
```

Now you should ask yourself, what exactly you were expecting to do with `keyof T` where `T` is unconstrained?

If you want it to be a `string` then you can just do `idName: string`
If you want to pass an object then you'll need to start constraining your generic.

Simple example to constraint the `T` in the `TableConfig` to be an object always:

```js
interface TableConfig<T extends {}> {
  idName: keyof T;
}
```

You can find more in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints)

And of course if you constrain it then in the `Table<T>` where you do:
`tableConfig: TableConfig<T>` will give you error since you try to pass an arbitrary type `T` to the constraint typed `T` in `TableConfig<T extends ...>`. So you might need to fix it also there.

Something also you could do is rethink the whole `Table` interface. Why should the "config" of the table depend so strong on the data? You could use for example multiple type parameters to handle the config type separately.

These are just ideas on how you could approach the issue, not exactly how to solve it since it depends on your use case. From what I get from your explanation just declaring `idName` to `string` would be probably enough.

**Edit**: By reading your post again I realized that I didn't focus on the exact issue as I should. So here is some extra clarification on your issue.

By the definition `keyof` will give you most of the times a literal union (see below for some other cases). There is no way of using the `keyof` operator to result in a string.

Even if you try hard enough to force somehow `keyof` to give a string, you'll fail:

```js
interface O<T> {
  data: keyof T;
}

// try to force somehow that the key will be a string
const obj1: O<{[key: string]: any}> = {
  data: ... // data will result in type: `string | number`
}

// try to force again that the key will be a number (not a string)
const obj2: O<{[key: number]: any}> = {
  data: ... // data will result in type: `number`
}
```

In `obj1` even if you "force" the object keys to be strings, you can still pass numbers since in javascript object keys are always coerced into strings. Which means this: `obj[0]` will result in this `obj["0"]`.

`obj2` is an interesting case. If you force the key to be something else than a `string`, for example `number` then it will work as expected.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html

So, if you expect `tableConfig.idName` to be a string you shouldn't use `keyof`.